# Disable UICollectionView haptic feedback when moving cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, haptic-feedback

Is there a way to disable the haptic feedback happening when cells are swapped during moving ?

Comment: 3 years have passed and no one answer, thanks Apple for unaccessible API